# Customise title in renderTable and make it reactive R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server, shiny-reactivity

When I use paste0() to add a reactive value, it tells me that I'm trying to do something that can only be done in a reactive environment. Can someone show me how to make the title reactive?

this code gives a tiny title in renderTable. How can I customise with colour, size, font, centre? Thanks!

```
shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    fluidRow(
      column(12,
             tableOutput('table')
      )
    )
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {
    output$table <- renderTable(iris, striped = TRUE, bordered = TRUE, hover = TRUE, spacing = 'm',  
                                width = '75%', align = 'c', rownames = TRUE,  digits = 5,
                                caption = "Iris",
                                caption.placement = getOption("xtable.caption.placement", "top"))
  }
)
}
```

Comment: This might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50800892/change-rendertable-title-in-shiny